How to mount NAS as network storage for Paperless-ngx under Windows with WSL and Docker?
I have a Windows 11 System which runs Paperless-ngx on Docker and WSL and a Docker Volume as storage. Additionally I use Portainer for Docker UI. So far this setup works without problems.
Now I have a QNAP NAS and want to use it as storage path for Paperless-ngx.
As Windows drive
I mounted the NAS under Windows as Z drive and used this as Volume configuration in my Docker compose file:
Z:\Paperless\Data:/usr/src/paperless/data

But Docker does not mount the drive. Instead it's creating a new Docker volume.
I have also tried the following other configuration, but with the same result:
/mnt/z/Paperless/data:/usr/src/paperless/data

As WSL mount
An other approach was to mount the NAS directly to the WSL System under /mnt/data/.
Using \\wsl$ in Windows Explorer I can see the full path and can confirm the mounting was successfully, so I used it in my Docker compose file:
\\wsl.localhost\docker-desktop\mnt\nas\data\Paperless\Data:/usr/src/paperless/data

The result is an error message in Portainer:

Creating Error response from daemon: can't access specified distro mount service

As direct access
And last but not least I tried to access the NAS directly. First as docker volume with CIFS (using Portainer), and second using the IP in my compose file:
//192.168.0.123/Paperless/Data:/usr/src/paperless/data

But both lead again to a newly created Docker volume.
Just for debuging purpose I also tried this:
C:\Test:/usr/src/paperless/data

This works as expected and without Problems.
Is there any other way I can try to use my NAS as volume for Paperless-ngx on Docker with WSL?
